# SpringBoot with MariaDB: The driver has not received any packets from the server

Tags: mysql, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, hikaricp

I have a MariaDB, when connecting with sequel Pro I use this credentials and I can connect

[image]

with SpringBoot I use

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://172.105.50.55:3306/pradera_db
spring.datasource.username=pradera_usr
spring.datasource.password=Mddejh847h$#@
```

but I have this error:

```
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)
    at java.base/java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:400)
    at java.base/java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:243)
    at java.base/java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:225)
    at java.base/java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:402)
    at java.base/java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:591)
    at com.mysql.cj.protocol.StandardSocketFactory.connect(StandardSocketFactory.java:155)
    at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.NativeSocketConnection.connect(NativeSocketConnection.java:65)
    ... 81 common frames omitted
2020-05-31 12:30  [restartedMain] INFO  com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource - HikariPool-1 - Starting...
2020-05-31 12:30  [restartedMain] ERROR com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool - HikariPool-1 - Exception during pool initialization.
com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure

The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
```

this is the dependency in the pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this as connection string :

`spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://172.105.50.55:3306/pradera_db?useUnicode=true&useJDBCCompliantTimezoneShift=true&useLegacyDatetimeCode=false&serverTimezone=UTC`

pom.xml :

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>mysql</groupId>
    <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Are you able to create/drop tables with this user?

Comment: I've just edited my answer, I don't know if you have seen, database name was not yours...

Comment: And is the right dependency in the pom file? (H2 removed and mysql added?)

Comment: Remove H2 dependency.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/215095/discussion-between-manta-and-nunito-de-la-calzada).

Comment: Saved many hours after 2 already wasted hours! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

On the machine that's running your database add your ip as an allowed connection on the port 3306

Linux:

```
iptables -I INPUT -p tcp -s your.ip.address.here --dport 3306 -j ACCEPT
```

Windows:
Open the start menu, write in the search bar: Windows firewall, open advanced settings on the left, select inbound rules, press new rule button on the right, Select port and press next, select tcp and specify the port 3306, press next, Allow the connection and after that just finish by selecting Domain, private, public and choosing a name for the rule itself.

Check if the service is running and enable/start it.

Linux:

```
sudo systemctl status mariadb
sudo systemctl enable mariadb
sudo systemctl start mariadb
```

Windows: Open the start menu, search for **Services.msc**, inside the services tab find your mariadb service and modify it's status by right clicking it.

Hope it helps.